# PHP: Comparing two Arrays with "array_diff" only returns "Array ( )"

Tags: php, arrays, compare, array-difference

I have two Arrays (but in reality they have much more content):

Array $erg

```
Array ( [0] => 4004708326000 [1] => 4004708392555 [2] => 4004708385106)
```

and Array $eannummer:

```
Array ( [0] => 4004708326000 [1] => 4004708392555 [2] => 4004708285234)
```

I tried to compare them with array_diff to get all the Numbers that are in $erg but not in $eannummer

```
print_r (array_diff($erg, $eannummer));
```

this only prints out

```
Array ()
```

but I can't manage to find out why...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. http://3v4l.org/FLqdC Please show your code

Answer (score 1):

babl@wks35:~$ cat 17.php 
It works for me:

```
<?php
$erg = Array ( 0 => 4004708326000, 1 => 4004708392555, 2 => 4004708385106);
$eannummer = Array ( 0 => 4004708326000, 1 => 4004708392555, 2 => 4004708285234);

print_r($erg);
print_r($eannummer);
print_r(array_diff($eannummer,$erg));
print_r(array_diff($erg,$eannummer));
?>
babl@wks35:~$ php 17.php 
Array
(
    [0] => 4004708326000
    [1] => 4004708392555
    [2] => 4004708385106
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4004708326000
    [1] => 4004708392555
    [2] => 4004708285234
)
Array
(
    [2] => 4004708285234
)
Array
(
    [2] => 4004708385106
)
```

Comment: Of course this does work, but I have almost 500 entries in array $erg and 300 in array $eannummer, when I try to compare the whole arrays, it does not seem to work for me....

Comment: And how we can check this? Put your "not working" code to pastebin or dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

**This is help you**

```
$resultDiff = array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

[`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array-diff)